# Show $f: [0,1] ^{\mathbb{N}}\to [1,e]^{\mathbb{N}}: (x_{i})_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto (e^{x_{i}})_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, continuity

We consider the function $f: [0,1] ^{\mathbb{N}}\to [1,e]^{\mathbb{N}}: (x_{i})_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto (e^{x_{i}})_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, where $[0,1]$ and $[1,e]$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$ with the euclidean topology. How can I show that $f$ is a homeomorphism?

Here we need the definition of a general cartesian product to express $[1,e]^{\mathbb{N}}$.

$$[1,e]^{\mathbb{N}}:=\{g: \mathbb{N} \to [1,e]: n \mapsto g_{n} \}$$

An element of this set is denoted by $(g_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

The bijectivity is very easy to show. However, I have problems to show the continuity of $f$ and $f^{-1}$.
A sufficient and necessary condition for the continuity of $f$ is that $$\forall n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}:p_{n_{0}} \circ f: [0,1] ^{\mathbb{N}}\to [1,e]$$
,where $p_{n_{0}}:[1,e]^{\mathbb{N}} \to [1,e]:(g_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto g_{n_{0}}$, is continuous.

The product topology on $\prod_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha}$ is defined by the topology which basis is $$\{\prod_{\alpha \in A} U_{\alpha}:U_{\alpha}\space\text{is an open set of}\space X_{\alpha},\forall \alpha \in A\space \text{and}\space U_{\alpha}=X_{\alpha} \space \text{except for a finite number of} \space \alpha \text{'s}\}$$

Intuitively the fact that the function is continuous seems clear to me, but I don't know how to prove it. Maybe with the latter definition I could show that the preimage by $p_{n_{0}} \circ f$ of an open set in $\mathbb{N}$ is an open set in $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$, which would prove the continuity of $f$. I don't expect a full answer, I would already be grateful if you could give me tips/ help me in solving this problem step by step.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can show that $\pi_n \circ f$ is equivalent to $g \circ \pi_n$ (this projection is from $[0, 1]^{\mathbb{N}} \to [0, 1]$) where $g(x) = e^x$.  Since both of these functions are continuous and the composition of continuous functions is continuous you have that $f$ is continuous.. Then again I'm still quite green with topology so maybe that's gibberish.

Comment: This might work. With "equivalent" you mean that for all $x$ in $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ we have $(p_n \circ f)(x) = (g \circ \pi_n)(x)$?
With $p_n$ defined as in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following two facts about the product topology:

(1) A function **into** a product space is continuous if and only if all of its components are continuous.

(2) The natural projections onto components **from** a product space to each component are continuous.

Comment: I agree with $(2)$, but $(1)$ is only true for finite product spaces, so one needs to use the property with $p_{n_{0}} \circ f$ that I wrote in my question.

Comment: I am quite certain (1) is true also in the general case.